# Обрезка текста до второй заглавной буквы

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Всем добрый день!
Появилась проблема, я в регулярных выражениях силен не особо, возможно мне сможет кто нибудь помочь?
У меня есть текст

```
$full="Иван купил мопед Рига в Москве";
```

В итоге мне нужно текст разбить на две части:
Первая часть должна состоять из текста "Иван купил мопед".
Вторая часть текста должна состоять из оставшихся символов "Рига в Москве".

Как я понял мне нужно регулярное выражение которое (часть 1)первым шагом возьмет текст с начала и до буквы "Р" затем загонит ее в переменную к примеру `$cuts`.

Затем я уже смогу вырезав $cuts из полного $full и получу вторую часть.

Но я ни как не могу справиться с первой частью :( тонкость в том что мне нужно выражение которое возьмет весь текст до второй заглавной буквы "Р", она всегда заглавная вторая. Города только меняются, и имена.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте

```
'~^(\P{Lu}*\p{Lu}.*?)\s*(\p{Lu}.*)$~us'
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/rdosEy/2).

**Подробности**

- `^` - началостроки
- `(\P{Lu}*\p{Lu}.*?)` - Захватывающая подмаска №1:

  - `\P{Lu}*` - 0 и более символов, отличных от заглавных букв
  - `\p{Lu}` - заглававная буква
  - `.*?` - 0 и более любых символов, но как можно меньше
- `\s*` -  - 0 и более пробельных символов
- `(\p{Lu}.*)` - Захватывающая подмаска №2:

  - `\p{Lu}` - заглававная буква
  - `.*` - 0 и более любых символов, но как можно больше (до конца строки)
- `$` - конец строки.

[PHP-код](https://ideone.com/zM3TDa):

```
$re = '~^(\P{Lu}*\p{Lu}.*?)\s*(\p{Lu}.*)$~us';
$str = 'Иван купил мопед Рига в Москве';
if (preg_match($re, $str, $match)) {
    echo $match[1] . "\n" . $match[2];
}
```

Результат:

```
Иван купил мопед
Рига в Москве
```